# Android crashes while sending json object

Tags: json, android-volley

I am trying to send json object through volley in android studio to a server (mvc spring project in eclipse + tomcat is listening) but the app crashes. I'm new to the volley library. Also, the json object is made up of the data gotten from user inputs in combo box and textviews.

**Login Activity:**

```
package com.example.mujtaba.quizzer;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.example.mujtaba.quizzer.Activity.QuizMaking;
import com.example.mujtaba.quizzer.Activity.QuizTaking;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    private TextView username;
    private TextView password;
    private Spinner role;
    private String url = "http://localhost:8080/users/signup";
    private RequestQueue queue;
    private ProgressDialog progress;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        role = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.role);

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.role_spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        role.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void Quiz(View v) {   //select a new activity on the basis of role

// Instantiate the cache
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

// Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

// Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
        queue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

// Start the queue
        queue.start();


        StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //This code is executed if the server responds, whether or not the response contains data.
                //The String 'response' contains the server's response.
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //This code is executed if there is an error.
            }
        }) {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String,String>();
                MyData.put("Username", username.getText().toString() ); //Add the data you'd like to send to the server.
                MyData.put("Password",password.getText().toString());
                MyData.put("Role",role.getSelectedItem().toString());
                MyData.put("Score","0");
                return MyData;
            }
        };

        queue.add(MyStringRequest);
    }
}
```

**Logcat error:**

```
*3430-3440/com.android.dialer E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                              java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                                                  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                                                  at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                                                  at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
                                                                  at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
                                                                  at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
                                                                  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)*
```